# Uniqueness in $C([0,T])$ of solution found by Picard-Lindelof Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Full statement of the question:

Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, also $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}), and f(0) = 0$

Consider the following ODE:

> $\partial_{t} u(t) = f(u(t)), \ \text{for} \ 0 < t < T $
>
> $u(0) = \alpha $

where $u:[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is unknown, and the integral equation:

> $u(t) = \alpha + \int^{t}_{0} f(u(s)) \text{d}s, \ 0<t<T $

Prove that there exists $T>0$ such that the above integral equation has a unique solution $u \in C([0, T])$. Furthermore, show that $u$ satisfies $u \in C^{1}([0, T])$ and the above ODE.

My Question:

I have shown just about every point of this question, by using the Picard-Lindelof theorem on the following set:

$X = \{ u \in C([0,T]) : u(0) = \alpha , || u - \alpha || \leq K\}$,

where $K \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} , \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and the norm is $|| u || = ^{\text{sup}}_{t \in (0,T)} |u(t)|$.

However, while this proves there is a $T>0$ such that a solution unique in $X$ exists, I cannot figure how to show such a solution is unique in all of $C([0,T])$. Can someone please inform me how I might show this?

Comment: Assume another solution $v$ exists, then $$|u(t)-v(t)|\le \int_0^t| f(u)-f(v)|\, ds, $$ and now use the Lipschitz condition on $f$ and the Gronwall lemma.

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, I'm afraid I am not familiar with this lemma. I have just read the wikipedia page for it, and I fail to see how it is used for this problem. Could you please elaborate slightly? Thank you.

Comment: Never mind. I see. I can use it to assert that $|u - v| = 0$. Thank you very much

Comment: If you use Picard-Lindelöf, then you can also use the uniqueness statement that is part of its claim.

Comment: @LutzL, Sorry, to be clear, I had to show the Picard-Lindelof theorem is true myself.

Comment: Then the uniqueness is usually a consequence of the uniqueness claim of the Banach fixed-point theorem that is used in the proof.

Comment: @lutzl: this is, according to me, a common (mild) mistake. The contraction mapping theorem implies uniqueness **in a small ball** centered around the constant function. Who says that there is not another solution, far away from that constant function? Of course the result is true, and uniqueness does hold, but there is a little more work to do, it is not just an immediate consequence of the contraction mapping theorem. I suggested to use the Gronwall inequality, but if course there are also other ways.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : And any other solution to the IVP has to enter the ball around $α$ of radius $K$, and the part inside the ball has to coincide with the local solution. There can be no other solution somewhere far away outside the ball that has the same initial value, as all solutions are continuous (and differentiable).

Comment: Could you please correct/clarify the question in regards to the role of $T$? In some places it seems that $T$ is some given, fixed quantity, in others it appears as something that is constructed in the proof. Your final question seems non-sensical in light of that, you have found a $T$ with those properties but still want to prove these same properties with the same $T$.

Comment: @LutzL, The Picard Lindelof theorem only explicitly proves that the solution is unique in the set $X$ described above. My request was for a method to $ \textbf{explicitly}$ prove that the solution is unique in all $C([0,T])$. Giuseppe Negro has provided me with such a method.

Comment: But what is the $T$? If it is constructed as in the Picard-Lindelöf proof, then any solution of the IVP in $C([0,T])$ is automatically, by construction and the mean value theorem, contained in $X$. If $T$ is something else, please specify that explicitly so that your question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work so far has shown that there exists a solution $u$ which is unique in the subset $B_K(\alpha)$ (the $K$ ball around the constant function $\alpha$ in $C([0,t])$.  We want to show this function is in fact unique in the whole space $C([0,t])$.

Suppose $v \in C([0,t])$ is also a solution to the IVP, and let $\tau = \inf\left(\{T\} \cup \{t: t < T, |v(t) - \alpha| > K\}\right)$.  Note that, since $v$ is continuous and $v(0) = \alpha$, we must have that $\tau > 0$.

Observe that, 
$$u, v \in Y := \{w \in C([0,\tau]) : \sup_{[0,\tau]} |w(t) -\alpha| \leq K\}$$
and as a corollary of the Picard-Lindelof contraction argument you performed, you can conclude that $u \equiv v$ on $[0,\tau]$ (intuitively, we still get uniqueness if we look over a shorter time-scale).  If $\tau = T$, then $u \equiv v$ in $C([0,t])$.  Since this is the result we want, our goal now is to show that $\tau < T$ gives a contradiction.

Suppose $\tau < T$, and let $\beta = u(\tau)$.  By the definition of $\tau$,  for any $\tau < s < T$, $|v(s)| > K \geq |u(s)|$.  This means that the IVP
$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \partial_s w(s) = f(w(s)) &\qquad \tau < t < T\\
 w(\tau) = u(\tau)&
\end{array}\right.$$
has two solutions in any set $Z = \{w \in C([\tau, T^*]) : \lVert w - \beta \rVert < M\}$ for any $M > 0$ and $T^* > \tau$, since $u$ and $v$ instantly separate after time $\tau$.  But, you proved earlier that we can always find a 'locally unique' solution to this ODE, so this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard proof of the *Picard-Lindelöf existence and uniqueness theorem for IVP* in the setup of an autonomous ODE, one first fixes some value for the radius $K$ (so that, at least, the ball of radius $K$ is contained in the domain of $f$). Then one obtains the maximum $M$ of the norm of function values $\|f(x)\|$ over the ball $x\in \bar B(α,K)$. Now the condition $MT\le K$ provides a first bound for $T$. It ensures by the mean value theorem that any solution $u\in C([0,T])$ of the initial value problem, if it exists, stays inside that ball, as
$$
\|u(t)-α\|=\left\|\int_0^tf(u(s))\,ds\right\|\le\int_0^t\|f(u(s))\|\,ds\le Mt\le MT\le K\tag1
$$
That is, any function in $C([0,T])$ that solves the IVP is automatically contained in $X$.

Next one further reduces the time interval by adding the restriction $2LT\le 1$ where $L$ is the local Lipschitz constant of $f$ on $B(α,K)$ to ensure contractivity of the integral operator in the maximum norm. With everything now fixed you apply the Banach fixed-point theorem that ensures the actual existence of a local solution in $X$ as well as its uniqueness. To repeat, by construction of $T=\min(\frac{K}M,\frac1{2L})$, there can be no solutions in $C([0,T])$ that are outside of $X$, see inequality (1).

As a consequence one gets that any solution in $C([0,b))$, $b>T$, when restricted to $[0,T]$ has to coincide with this local solution. Repeated application of that argument can also serve to show that the solution is unique as long as it exists. Because if that were not the case, there would be a first point $t_0$ where two solutions diverge from each other, resp. the last point where they are still the same. However, the IVP with $u(t_0)$ as initial value at $t=t_0$ has a unique local solution, so $t_0$ can not be the minimum under consideration.